# How to aproach that this equation has infinite positive solutions?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I have this equation:

$$ \frac{x+1}{\sqrt{{x}^{2}+1}}=2\,\mathrm{cos}\left( x\right)  $$

and I'm asked to argue that it has infinite positive solutions.

So I try to simplify the equation and I get to this:

$$ x=\mathrm{cos}\left( 2\,x\right) +1 $$

but now I don't know how to argue that it has infinite positive solutions or how to aproach it.

Comment: Your simplification is wrong and actually you don't need it. Hint: for positive $x$ try to see what are the values of $\frac{x+1}{2\sqrt{x^2+1}}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $x\to+\infty$, the left hand side converges to $1$, hence for $x$ big enough it stays strictly between $\frac12$ and $\frac32$, wheras the right hand side oscillates between $-2$ and $2$. By the IVT, there exist a solution each time the cosine goes up or down.

Comment: @user137201: 1 is between 1/2 and 3/2...

Answer (score 0):

Hint: what happens to $$\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$ as $x\to\infty$? And what is the amplitude of $2\cos x$?

Answer (score 0):

Your simplification is wrong.
I think you'll find the right hand side of your equation is bounded above and below, and if you draw the graph, it crosses the graph of 2cos(2x) an infinite number of times!

Answer (score 0):

$$1<\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}<\sqrt2,$$

because, after squaring
$$x^2+1< x^2+2x+1<2x^2+2,$$
or
$$0<2x< x^2+1,$$
or 
$$0< x\land 0<(x-1)^2$$
(except for $x=1$).

Increasing $x$ to infinity, $2\cos x$ goes from $1$ to $\sqrt2$ infinitely many times, and both functions are continuous, so they cross each time.